# Como pegar o nome de uma variável dentro de um método?

Tags: c#, variáveis

Eu preciso acessar o nome de uma variável dentro de um método.

Exemplo:

```
public class A
{
   public A()
   {
     string nameToWrite = "thisdoesntmatter";
     B.GetName(nameToWrite);
   }
}

public class B
{
   public static GetName(string nameIrrelevant)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(nameof(nameIrrelevant));
   }
}
```

Mas o retorno é esse:

> nameIrrelevant

E queria que fosse:

> nameToWrite

Comment: Olá, este é o site do **stackoverflow** em português, traduza sua pergunta ou pergunte também no site em inglês

Comment: Qual a razão disso? O que realmente você precisa?

Comment: Você quer pegar o valor da variável ou apenas o nome da variável?

Comment: Creio que nem com *reflection* isso deve ser possível, não há ligação com a variável no outro método, mesmo passando por referência

Comment: @GabrielHeming Eu estou a construir uma classe generica que me interessa o nome do objeto diretamente passado.

Comment: @MayconF.Castro Essa questão está indicada no texto, só me interessa o nome da variavel que é passada e nao a interna, nem valores

Comment: @RicardoPontual Pois, eu já tentei de varias formas e não consigo chegar ao nome, mesmo com reflecion e propertInfo. Consigo aceder aos nomes das properiedades desse objeto com reflection mas o nome desse mesmo objeto não sei.

Comment: @PedroMartins pq nao obter o nome assim [`var nomeVariavel = nameof(nameToWrite);`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FoyqOz)? Tenha em conta que o nome das variaveis pode e provavelmente vai mudar depois de compilado.

Comment: Você não vai conseguir, pois, nomes de variáveis não são relevantes do ponto de vista de operação. Apenas em questões de limitação de linguagem e/ou performance.

Comment: Deve ser na linha do que o @GabrielHeming comentou, e por isso quando você "descompila" um código os nomes das variáveis não são necessariamente os mesmo no código original.

Comment: Nota: o [`nameof`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) resolve o nome na altura da compilação (ou seja o nome vai ser o que vê e não existe nenhuma resolução durante a execução da aplicação)

Comment: Pelo visto você quer ir além. Além das excelentes respostas e comentários: Dê uma olhada no F#

Comment: @Tony o que o F# tem a oferecer nisso?

Comment: Ele oferece mais recursos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está falando de variáveis locais e estas são apenas apelidos para endereços de memória totalmente desnecessários para execução, é apenas uma abstração para facilitar o entendimento do programador.

Após a compilação não há nome de variável (local, em linguagens/implementações que sejam 100% nativas e **estáticas**, até mesmo símbolos não locais podem ser descartados), portanto não tem o que ser acessado. Se o exercício pede exatamente isto, e acho que não pede, que é interpretação errada, o exercício é falho e não faz sentido. Se não é um exercício, tem algo muito errado.

O que pode fazer é colocar um parâmetro no método e passar o nome como `string` como argumento para o método. Mesmo isto não faz sentido.

Lembrando que você sempre sabe o nome de variáveis **locais** durante o desenvolvimento, então não faz sentido criar um código para descobrir qual é o nome.

Mesmo o `nameof()` só existe como medida protetiva para evitar que o código dessincronize com o texto usado, assim se mudar o nome da variável, a compilação do `nameof()` falhará e você poderá mudar manualmente concordando que agora o outro nome é o correto. Quando usa a `string` direto com o nome da variável, se tinha um `"x"`, e a variável muda para `y`, o código fica com `"x"` e pode não ser notado. Na prática este operador faz nada real na aplicação.

Não faz sentido saber o nome da variável que foi usada para chamada do método, tem zero benefícios nisso. Nem deveria ter algum. As únicas linguagens onde faz sentido são as que possuem escopo dinâmico, que é uma das ideias mais idiotas já criadas na computação, e posso falar bem disso porque trabalhei com linguagem assim, mas que por sorte hoje é opcional, e mesmo quando era obrigatório fazer assim era melhor fazer de conta que nem podia se aproveitar disto.

Então não precisa acessar este nome. E se precisasse mesmo, deveria justificar. Quem sabe é um problema XY (vide ao lado se estiver lendo isso durante a Copa :D ). Este método `getName()` é simplesmente desnecessário e um erro de programação. Assim pode ter alguma relevância, ainda esquisito:

```
public class A {
    public A() {
        var nameToWrite = "thisdoesntmatter";
        B.WriteName(nameof(nameToWrite));
    }
}

public class B {
    public static WriteName(string name) => WriteLine(name));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Nameof.cs).

Note que mudei até o nome do método pra fazer sentido, e ele só deveria existir como abstração.

Isto é a mesma coisa:

```
public A() {
    var nameToWrite = "thisdoesntmatter";
    WriteLine("nameToWrite"); //o nameof() daria mais proteção contra alteração desavisada
}
```

Comment: Essa resposta é parcialmente boa, mas infelizmente nao serve para o âmbito do meu desenvolvimento. A opção ideal seria a classe A utilizar a classe B sem precisar de saber de "nameof" ou quaisquer metadata. Mas do que vejo não será possivel

Comment: Não temos como saber seu âmbito sem você falar sobre ele. E duvido que isto seja possível, porque não faz sentido. tem requisitos artificiais que não resolvem nada. Não é que não é possível, não é necessário.

Comment: O âmbito é criar uma classe genérica para programadores utilizarem, o objetivo é converter object em data structured string (um tipo feito por mim, nao é XML nem JSON...) mas era interessante que quando o programador passa-se o seu objeto para dentro da outra classe que seria uma incognica, e ele criava a string com o nome inicial da variavel.

Comment: De qualquer das formas, já arranjei um work-around para esta questão.

Comment: Cada vez fica mais claro que é a solução errada para o problema, ou no mínimo a pergunta errada para a necessidade. Você pode ter achado uma solução, mas se foi nesse caminho, ela está errada.

Comment: @PedroMartins o que voê chama de *work-around* na verdade é chamada de gambiarra desnecessária, porque o problema sequer é este. Até acrescentei algum mais na resposta, mas é isto, não tem motivos para fazer o que quer.